# Stopped process reasons?

Tags: linux, bash, c, executable

I'm running a program using a batch file and it keep giving me this ERROR:

> STOPPED PROCESS

I've noticed that the program stops each time in a place a little after the place he stopped the last time i executed it

Now i'm looking for the ***Stopped process*** reasons or it's gonna be even much better if someone passed through the same problem!

Thanks.

Comment: This needs to be much more detailed to be answerable. The message you're getting is certainly not a well-known message from one of the standard OS components. What program are you running? What exactly do you mean by "using a batch file"? What exactly happens when you get the message?

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of problems are usually related with the reception of `SIGSTOP` signal; signal that is usually related with the **CTRL + Z** combination; after the "stopped process" message, type the **`jobs`** command, if you find your program there, that means that your program has received that signal.

In that case, check your code and also be careful and check your logs to see if some kind of background program is sending that signal.

I also add the signal documentation where you can check all the signal values, including the ones for SIGSTOP:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html